# Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression using input[name]:checked selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am coding on a social media and it was working pretty neat until i checked it out on safari. Here it keeps throwing me this error which i can't solve myself - i've tried;). The error appears as soon as you visit my settings page where i have an ajax request that sends the data to my backend. It's like the safari engine thinks that there is a missing end bracket. I am using jQuery v3.3.1

**The error**

```
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: input[name='assault'     
(anonymous function) - jquery.js 2:31048
```

**important html code**

```
<form id="settingsForm">    
    <div>
       <label>
         <div><img src="images/loggedin/csgo/assault.png"></div>
         <div class="hidden"><input type="checkbox" name="assault" value="1"></div>
        </label>
    </div>
</form>
```

**important jquery code**

```
$(document).on("submit", "#settingsForm", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var assault     = $("input[name='assault']:checked").val();
        if (assault != "1") { assault = ""; }

        //doing my ajax request here...
});
```

Comment: Can't reproduce: http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/xct6kp0s/3/ Are you sure you copied the code correctly?

Comment: Yep, 100% sure - just double checked

Comment: Please create  a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem There's nothing wrong with the expression you show.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following approach and see if it works.

Instead if using the ":checked" within the same selector when checking by name, you can try to use the is() method.

```
if(!$("input[name='assault']").is(":checked")){
    // checkbox is not checked
}
```

Also, you could check which version of Safari are you using and whether this is supported. [jQuery - Browser Support](https://jquery.com/browser-support/)

Comment: He wants to test the value of the checked box, not just test if the box is checked.

Comment: Yes, I understood that from the code. Based on the jQuery selector, the value only be one if the checkbox is checked. Why applying a second condition if the first decides everything?

Comment: Would kinda be the same to me but unfortunately this isn't the error.... I just tried to serialize the form and the name=assault doesn't even show up. i guess my issue is somewhere else...

Comment: @gamerneskonge Could you be disabling the input? That will prevent it from being serialized.

Comment: @gamerneskonge would that be possible to check it in other browser? Also, Barmar had a good point at his first comment. The error message does not reflect the actualy code you have shared. Based on the error message, the jQuery code should look like: $("input[name]:checked").val();. Can you please check whether you have provided the correct code for us to investigate?

Comment: Okay, so the error wasn't in the question but a result of some other bad code... sry for your time guys

Answer (score -1):

If you are curious about what the error was... here u go. im gonna delete this question shortly

```
            function addColorROLE(toDo){

            var roles       = ["assault", "sniper", "csgosupport", "assasin", "fighter", "mage", "marksman", "lolsupport", "tank"];
            var rolesCsgo   = ["assault", "sniper", "csgosupport"];
            var rolesLOL    = ["assasin", "fighter", "mage", "marksman", "lolsupport", "tank"];

            if (toDo == "1"){
                var checkChecked = 0;
                while (roles.length - 1 >= checkChecked){
                    if ($("input[name='"+roles[checkChecked]+"'").prop("checked")){
                        $("input[name='"+roles[checkChecked]+"'").parent().parent().find("img").addClass("pickedRole");
                        $("input[name='"+roles[checkChecked]+"'").parent().parent().prepend('<div class="selectedCheckedS"><img src="images/overall/check.png"></div>');
                    } else {
                        $("input[name='"+roles[checkChecked]+"'").parent().parent().find("img").removeClass("pickedRole");
                        $("input[name='"+roles[checkChecked]+"'").parent().parent().find(".selectedCheckedS").remove();
                    }
                    checkChecked++;
                }
            } else if (toDo == "2"){
                var checkedTwo = 0;
                while (rolesLOL.length - 1 >= checkedTwo){  
                    $("input[name='"+rolesLOL[checkedTwo]+"'").prop("checked", true);
                    $("input[name='"+rolesLOL[checkedTwo]+"'").parent().parent().find("img").addClass("pickedRole");
                    $("input[name='"+rolesLOL[checkedTwo]+"'").parent().parent().prepend('<div class="selectedCheckedS"><img src="images/overall/check.png"></div>');   
                    checkedTwo++;
                }
            } else if (toDo == "3"){
                var checkedThree = 0;
                while (rolesCsgo.length - 1 >= checkedThree){
                    $("input[name='"+rolesCsgo[checkedThree]+"'").prop("checked", true);
                    $("input[name='"+rolesCsgo[checkedThree]+"'").parent().parent().find("img").addClass("pickedRole");
                    $("input[name='"+rolesCsgo[checkedThree]+"'").parent().parent().prepend('<div class="selectedCheckedS"><img src="images/overall/check.png"></div>');    
                    checkedThree++;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Right. That is how some of the selectors had no value resulting in incorrect syntax. Wouldn't be a bad idea to leave the question as is, it may help someone some day :)

Comment: Yeah, so stupid right? I guess it's the result of too much coffee and too little sleep. I srsly think i went through the whole script 10 times without "finding" a single error.

Comment: Don't you worry. We all been there. That is the moment when you get some rest, or take a 10 minutes walk. Even if just do something different for a little while will improve your focus and eventually get you see things from a different view.